# Phalcon PHP multi module namespace definition

Tags: php, namespaces, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon PHP with [Multi module application](https://docs.phalconphp.com/fr/latest/reference/applications.html#multi-module). I'm using namespace in my project but I'm searching for something to use theses namespace.

For example, in my view folder I'm using the models folder and in my controller I use the models folder too. But I'm using lot of class models to do a Phalcon find or findFirst. And the only way than I found to make this multi apps working, it's to define the namespace used to import the class like this :

```
use Apps\Common\Models\Users;
use Apps\Common\Models\Customers;
use Apps\Common\Models\Agents;
...
```

And I have 50 models like this in my apps... I don't want to define them in all my controller and all my view to make it work.

Do you have a solutions for that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can omit the namespace declaration on top of your controller file:

```
use Models\News;

class NewsController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // With Use above
        $obj = new News();

        // Without Use above (full namespace path)
        $obj = new \Models\News();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then if I use 10 models in each controller I must put on top of each controller `use`x 10 ? And In my view I have to do this too... :( because I don't like this way `$obj = new \Models\News();`

Comment: Yes, you have to choose one of the two options. That's the idea of namespaces and it can not be avoided :)

Comment: Okay thanks. And this is possible to not use the namespace way in multi module application ? Because in phalcon single application I never use the namesace, I'm using the registerClasses and registerDir. It is possible here ?

Comment: Technically yes, but I doubt it is a good idea. If your application grows as you stated it will be hard to maintain. More info here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html#registering-classes

Trust me, namespaces are your friend :)

Comment: Okay I trust you :D. I'll set a namespace everywhere in my project. Do you have a security plugin in your multi module application ? I have to set the namespace to my security plugin too ? And where I can set the dispatcher in the DI ? In the Module.php ? Or in the bootstrap file ?

Comment: You can check phalcon structures here: https://github.com/phalcon/mvc and choose the one that suits your needs best or see how they are built. About security plugin if it's needed in all modules you can set it in bootstrap, if its only per one module, or it has module specific configuration you can go for Module.php

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot Nikki I'll try this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108961/discussion-between-john-and-niki-mihaylov).